# Looping through an Ember JS RSVP hash?

Tags: ember.js, rsvp.js

Code speaks a thousand words; is there a way to do what I'm attempting here?

**Users "Root" Route**

Loading common selectable options at the top level for use within sub-routes such as `index`, `show`, `edit`, `create`, etc...

```
-- /pods/users/route.js

model() {
    return RSVP.hash({
        userCategories: this.store.findAll('user-category'),
        userSources:    this.store.findAll('user-source'),
        userGroups:     this.store.findAll('user-group'),
    });
},
```

**Users "Create" Route**

With the sub-route of `/create` I want to loop through the already-loaded options above and load them into the template as named variables:

```
-- /pods/users/create/route.js

setupController(controller, model) {

    let rootModel = this.modelFor('users');

    rootModel.forEach(function (model, name) {
        set(controller, name, model);
    }); <-- THIS IS THE BROKEN PART...

    ...

}
```

**The Problem**

On the `.forEach` loop I am getting `Error while processing route: rootModel.forEach is not a function TypeError: rootModel.forEach is not a function`

Is there an "Ember Way" of looping through that root model, or will I be stuck with loading it in within a top level variable, ie;

```
-- /pods/users/create/route.js

setupController(controller, model) {

    let rootModel = this.modelFor('users');

    set(controller, 'rootModel', rootModel);

    ...

}
```

Comment: Why would you need to loop through it? With the way you defined your model hook now, you can access  the data in the template with i.e `{{#each model.userCategories as |category|}}`

Comment: I guess it's more a readability preference, I would prefer to be able to access `userCategories` without the leading `model`. Logically I know it doesn't really matter either way but to me `{{#each userCategories as |userCategory|}}` just seems cleaner.

Answer (score 4):

```
Object.keys(rootModel).forEach(function(name) {
  var model = rootModel[keyName];
  set(controller, name, model);
  // ...
});
```

or possible you just need not `RSVP.hash` but `RSVP.all` which return a promise which resolves with array contains resolved values?